# How to suppress ResourceWarning()s in doctest running under unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest, suppress-warnings, doctest

My Python [doctests](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) open some files that it never closes. This causes no problems; they're automatically closed when the object is destroyed and adding logic to ensure they're expicitly closed would unnecessarily complicate my documentation.

However, when the doctests run inside of [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), they start issuing `ResourceWarning()`s, adding unhelpful noise to my output.

For example, given leak.py:

```
def hello(f):
    """ 
    >>> a = open("test-file","w")
    >>> hello(a)
    >>> open("test-file").read()
    'hello'
    """
    f.write("hello")
    f.flush()

def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    import doctest
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite())
    return tests
```

Running it under doctest and unittest with Python 3.6.9 generates:

```
$ python3 --version
Python 3.6.9
$ python3 -m doctest leak.py -v
[...] 
3 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
$ python3 -m unittest leak
/tmp/fileleak/leak.py:1: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test-file' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
  def hello(f):
/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py:2175: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='test-file' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
  test.globs.clear()
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.003s

OK
```

There are a few ways to to clean this up inside the doctests, but they all add complexity that would be distracting in the documentation. This incudes explict calls to `a.close()`, using `with open("test-file") as a:` (which also pushes the tested output below the `with` block, or outright discarding warnings with `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")`.

How can I get doctests running under `unittest` to suppress the `ResourceWarning()`s like `doctest` does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doctest` is *not* suppressing these warnings. `unittest` is
enabling them. We probably *want* `unittest` to enable them for our more
traditional unittests, so we don't want to suppress these globally.

I'm already using [`load_tests`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) to add the doctests to `unittest`, so we've got
a good place to put it. We can't just call [`warnings.filterwarnings()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) directly
in `load_tests` as the filters are reset before our test is run. We *can* use
the `setUp` argument to [`doctest.DocTestSuite`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestSuite) to provide a function to do the job for us.

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, ignore):
    import doctest
    import warnings
    def setup(doc_test_obj):
        for module in (__name__, 'doctest'):
            warnings.filterwarnings("ignore",
                    message= r'unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper',
                    category=ResourceWarning,
                    module=module+"$")
    tests.addTests(doctest.DocTestSuite(setUp=setup))
    return tests
```

We need the filters anywhere where an object we created might be destroyed and
a `ResourceWarning` generated.  This includes our own module (`__name__`), but it
also includes `doctest` as some globals aren't destroyed until
`DocTestCase.tearDown`.

By carefully specifying what to filter by category, message, and modules, this
should limit the risk of suppressing designed warnings, but it's not risk free.